# Let $F$ be a closed subset of a metric space $X$. Does there exist a continuous function $g : X \to R$ such that $F = g^{-1}({0})$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $F$ be a closed subset of a metric space $X$. Does there exist a continuous function
$g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F = g^{-1}({0})$? I am trying to produce a counterexample to this. Any ideas would be really helpful

Comment: $d(x,F)$ and some other random characters to reach the minimum allowed length of a comment

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti how should I prove that d is continuous?

Comment: @thedumbkid check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153765/continuous-function-on-metric-space?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $F=\emptyset$ we can take $g: x \to \Bbb R$ to be a constant function with value $1$, so that $g^{-1}[\{0\}] = \emptyset = F$. So we can assume that $F \neq \emptyset$.

Let $f(x) = \inf \{d(x,y): y \in F\}$, which is well-defined as the infimum of a non-emptys set that is bounded below (by $0$) in $\Bbb R$.

Then it's not too hard to see that $$\forall x,x' \in X: |f(x)-f(x')| \le d(x,x')$$ which makes $f$ uniformly continuous.

And it's also clear that any $x$ which is a limit point of $F$ obeys $d(x,F)=0$ and the same holds for all $x \in F$, so that $F= f^{-1}[\{0\}]$. So use $g=f$, the distance to the set function.